# Formulario de Laravel Jetstream no funciona

Tags: laravel

Resolví un problema de urls en Laravel 8 Jetstream agregando a los href de los link el helper url ****osea: {{url('link')}}**** pero ahora dejaron de funcionar todos los botones y formularios de las view a las que accedo (profile y API Tokens). Cuando le doy al Submit se recarga el formulario pero la información no se sube, así que quizás el problema sean los action o href. El action se encuentra en el documento *App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation* según la documentación, pero yo no modifique el código en esos documentos.

**App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation:**

```
    class UpdateUserProfileInformation implements UpdatesUserProfileInformation
{
    /**
     * Validate and update the given user's profile information.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return void
     */
    public function update($user, array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
            'photo' => ['nullable', 'image', 'max:1024'],
        ])->validateWithBag('updateProfileInformation');

        if (isset($input['photo'])) {
            $user->updateProfilePhoto($input['photo']);
        }

        $user->forceFill([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
        ])->save();
    }
}
```